# HTML Form Align buttons and other modifications

Tags: html, css

I have to create an Educational Website Template to get started. I need help to make the following changes:

1. Remove the rounded corners on text boxes?
2. Display the Login and Reset buttons in the same line (horizontally)
3. Align the text of the Radio buttons and check boxes.

Here is my HTML script:

```html
<form name="mylogin" action="validatepassword.php" method="post" id="mylogin">
  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
    <tr align="center" valign="top">
      <td>
        <p align="center">
          <font size="5">Novell Services Login</font>
        </p>
        <table align="center" border="0">
          <tr align="left">
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="username" size="30">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="left">
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td>
              <input type="password" name="password" size="30">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="left">
            <td>City of
              <br>Employment:</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="city" size="30">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="left">
            <td>Web server:</td>
            <td>
              <select name="webserv" size="1">
                <option value="default" selected>--- Choose a server ---</option>
                <option value="Human Resources">Human Resources</option>
                <option value="Development">Development</option>
                <option value="Accounting">Accounting</option>
                <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="left" height="25" valign="top">
              <p></p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="left">
            <td>Please specify
              <br>your role:</td>
            <td>
              <input name="role" value="admin" type="radio">Admin
              <br>
              <input name="role" value="engineer" type="radio">Engineer
              <br>
              <input name="role" value="manager" type="radio">Manager
              <br>
              <input name="role" value="guest" type="radio">Guest
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="left" height="25" valign="top" width="121">
              <p></p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="left">
            <td>Single Sign-on
              <br>to the following:</td>
            <td>
              <input name="mail" type="checkbox">Mail
              <br>
              <input name="payroll" type="checkbox">Payroll
              <br>
              <input name="selfservice" type="checkbox">Self-service
              <br>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <input value="Login" type="submit">
        <input type="reset">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: css is the key code here , post it

Comment: I agree, there's not much to do with HTML. It's all about styling (CSS).

Comment: post a fiddle sample of yours.. someone will help you..

Comment: 1. row 650, remove `border-radius:8px;` in the css stylesheet, 2-3. the code you pasted has the right alignment.. not sure any other stylesheet is overriding the current attributes you've posted? getting two buttons horizontal side by side is achieved by `float` http://jsfiddle.net/7erov65w/

Comment: Modified description to explain the problem better (based on comments and accepted answer), Improved code formatting and converted the code to a snippet (runnable code with a demo helps to visualize the issues). Removed jQuery tag as the question seems to be more about styling and alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the input apply the falowing css:

```
input {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius:0 ;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

for the radiobox and the buttons try this :

```
input[type="submit"],input[type="reset"],input[type="radio"] {
    display: inline;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/456tc85z/

Comment: i have removed these lines: .rounded, input, button, textarea, #header input, #footer input, #slide-wrapper figcaption, .avatar, #comments li, .faico a, #twitter, 
.pagination a, .pagination strong{border-radius:8px;}  but still don't know how to position buttons, radio and check as in the original form

Comment: `input[type="text"] {padding:3px;}`

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of your border-radius in the rounded-corners section will fix the checkboxes for you.
For the text-alignment check the css style if it has a text-align property that is set to the left, it could also be that the page does not have enough width. Same goes for the horizontal text.

Answer (score 0):

Add `class="no-round"` to the inputs you want not rounded as follows and use the CSS code below

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="username" size="30" class="no-round">
```

**CSS**

```
 .row0, .row0 a {
}
.row1, .row1 a {
}
.row2, .row2 a {
}
.row3, .row3 a {
}
.row4, .row4 a {
}
.row5, .row5 a {
}
/* Top Bar
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 #topbar {
    padding:10px 0 0 0;
    text-align:right;
    font-size:.8em;
}
#topbar li {
    display:inline;
    margin-right:3px;
    padding-right:8px;
    border-right:1px solid;
}
#topbar li:last-child {
    margin-right:0;
    padding-right:0;
    border:none;
}
/* Header
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 #header {
}
#header #logo {
}
#header #logo h1 {
    margin:0 0 8px 0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:36px;
    line-height:12px;
    font-variant:small-caps;
    font-style:normal;
}
#header #logo p {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#header form {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
#header input, #header button {
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    border:none;
}
#header input {
    width:100%;
    min-width:250px;
    padding:5px 40px 5px 5px;
}
#header button {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width:35px;
    font-size:16px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#header button em {
    display:none;
}
/* Homepage Slider
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 #slider {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#slider .rounded {
    padding:9px;
}
#slider a, #slider ul, #slider img {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    list-style:none;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#slide-wrapper, #slide-wrapper figure, #slide-wrapper img {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#slide-wrapper figure, #slide-wrapper figure img {
    position:relative;
}
#slide-wrapper figure figcaption {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    right:25px;
    width:350px;
    height:200px;
    margin:0;
    padding:30px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#slide-wrapper figure figcaption p {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:1.6em;
}
#slider #slide-tabs {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:12px;
}
#slider #slide-tabs li {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
#slider #slide-tabs li a {
    display:block;
    width:192px;
    min-height:60px;
    padding:10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:solid;
    border-width:0 0 1px 1px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
#slider #slide-tabs li:last-child a {
    border-width:0 1px 1px 1px;
}
/* Content Area
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 .container {
    padding:20px 10px;
}
.container h1, .container h2, .container h3, .container h4, .container h5, .container h6, .container .heading {
    padding-bottom:8px;
    border-bottom:1px solid;
}
/* Content */
 .container #content {
}
#twitter {
    display:block;
    padding:15px;
}
#twitter div {
    padding:25px 0;
}
#twitter div:first-child {
    border-right:2px solid;
}
.listing li {
    margin:0 0 30px 0;
    padding:0 0 20px 0;
    border-bottom:1px solid;
}
.listing li:last-child {
    margin-bottom:0;
}
.mediacontainer, .mediacontainer iframe {
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.mediacontainer {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.quickinfo {
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
.quickinfo li {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    min-height:80px;
    margin:0 0 20px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.quickinfo li:last-child {
    margin-bottom:0;
}
.quickinfo li a {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    min-height:80px;
    padding:18px 0 0 80px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.quickinfo li a img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
}
/* Comments */
 #comments ul {
    margin:0 0 40px 0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
#comments li {
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    padding:15px;
}
#comments .avatar {
    float:right;
    margin:0 0 10px 10px;
    padding:3px;
    border:1px solid;
}
#comments address {
    font-weight:bold;
}
#comments time {
    font-size:smaller;
}
#comments .comcont {
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#comments .comcont p {
    margin:10px 5px 10px 0;
    padding:0;
}
#comments form {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
#comments input, #comments textarea {
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid;
}
#comments textarea {
    overflow:auto;
}
#comments div {
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
#comments input[type="submit"], #comments input[type="reset"] {
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
    min-width:150px;
    margin:0;
    padding:8px 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
/* Sidebar */
 .container .sidebar {
}
.sidebar .sdb_holder {
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
.sidebar .sdb_holder:last-child {
    margin-bottom:0;
}
/* Footer
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 #footer {
    padding:10px;
}
#footer .faico {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
#footer .faico li {
    margin:0 10px 0 0;
}
#footer .faico li:last-child {
    margin-right:0;
}
#footer .faico a {
    border:1px solid;
}
#footer form {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
#footer legend {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
#footer input, #footer button {
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    border:none;
}
#footer input {
    width:100%;
    min-width:250px;
    padding:5px 40px 5px 5px;
}
#footer button {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:35px;
    font-size:16px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#footer button em {
    display:none;
}
/* Copyright
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 #copyright {
}
#copyright p {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* Navigation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 nav ul, nav ol {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
#mainav .drop::after, #mainav li li .drop::after, #breadcrumb li a::after, .sidebar nav a::after {
    position:absolute;
    font-family:"FontAwesome";
    font-size:10px;
    line-height:10px;
}
/* Top Navigation */
 #mainav {
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
#mainav ul {
}
#mainav ul ul {
    z-index:9999;
    position:absolute;
    width:160px;
}
#mainav ul ul ul {
    left:160px;
    top:0;
}
#mainav li {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 30px 0 0;
    padding:0;
}
#mainav li:last-child {
    margin-right:0;
}
#mainav li li {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    text-align:left;
    text-transform:none;
}
#mainav li a {
    display:block;
    padding:0;
}
#mainav li li a {
    border:solid;
    border-width:0 0 1px 0;
}
#mainav li li:last-child a {
    border-bottom:none;
}
#mainav .drop {
    padding-left:15px;
}
#mainav li li a, #mainav li li .drop {
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:10px 15px;
}
#mainav .drop::after, #mainav li li .drop::after {
    content:"\f0d7";
}
#mainav .drop::after {
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
}
#mainav li li .drop::after {
    top:15px;
    left:5px;
}
#mainav ul ul {
    display:none;
}
#mainav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
#mainav form {
    display:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#mainav form select, #mainav form select option {
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
    outline:none;
}
#mainav form select {
    width:100%;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid;
}
#mainav form select option {
    margin:5px;
    padding:0;
    border:none;
}
/* Breadcrumb */
 #breadcrumb {
}
#breadcrumb ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
#breadcrumb li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 6px 0 0;
    padding:0;
}
#breadcrumb li a {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 12px 0 0;
    font-size:12px;
}
#breadcrumb li a::after {
    top:5px;
    right:0;
    content:"\f101";
}
#breadcrumb li:last-child a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#breadcrumb li:last-child a::after {
    display:none;
}
/* Sidebar Navigation */
 .sidebar nav {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
.sidebar nav li {
    margin:0 0 3px 0;
    padding:0;
}
.sidebar nav a {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:5px 10px 5px 15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:solid;
    border-width:0 0 1px 0;
}
.sidebar nav a::after {
    top:9px;
    left:5px;
    content:"\f101";
}
.sidebar nav ul ul a {
    padding-left:35px;
}
.sidebar nav ul ul a::after {
    left:25px;
}
.sidebar nav ul ul ul a {
    padding-left:55px;
}
.sidebar nav ul ul ul a::after {
    left:45px;
}
/* Pagination */
 .pagination {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    clear:both;
}
.pagination li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 2px 0 0;
}
.pagination li:last-child {
    margin-right:0;
}
.pagination a, .pagination strong {
    display:block;
    padding:8px 11px;
    border:1px solid;
    font-weight:normal;
    background-clip:padding-box;
}
/* Tables
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 table, th, td {
    border:1px solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    vertical-align:top;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
table, th {
    table-layout:auto;
}
table {
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
th, td {
    padding:5px 8px;
}
td {
    border-width:0 1px;
}
/* Gallery
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 #gallery {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
#gallery figure figcaption {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
}
#gallery li {
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
#gallery li a {
    display:block;
}
/* Portfolio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 #portfolio {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
#portfolio li, #portfolio img {
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
/* Font Awesome Social Icons
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 .faico {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.faico li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 2px 0 0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:normal;
}
.faico li:last-child {
    margin-right:0;
}
.faico a {
    display:block;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
.faico a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.faico a:hover {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
.faicon-facebook {
    background-color:#3B5998;
}
.faicon-flickr {
    background-color:#FF0084;
}
.faicon-linkedin {
    background-color:#0E76A8;
}
.faicon-rss {
    background-color:#EE802F;
}
.faicon-twitter {
    background-color:#00ACEE;
}
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* Rounded Corners
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 .rounded, input, button, textarea, #header input, #footer input, #slide-wrapper figcaption, .avatar, #comments li, .faico a, #twitter, .pagination a, .pagination strong {
    border-radius:8px;
}
.no-round{
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
#header button, #footer button {
    border-radius:0 8px 8px 0;
}
#mainav li li:first-child a, #mainav li li:first-child li:first-child a, #mainav li li:last-child li:first-child a {
    border-radius:8px 8px 0 0;
}
#mainav li li:last-child a, #mainav li li:last-child li:last-child a, #mainav li li:first-child li:last-child a {
    border-radius:0 0 8px 8px;
}
#mainav li li:first-child li a, #mainav li li:last-child li a {
    border-radius:0;
}
#slide-wrapper figure img, #slide-wrapper figure .view:hover::before {
    border-radius:8px 8px 0 0;
}
#slider #slide-tabs li:first-child a {
    border-radius:0 0 0 8px;
}
#slider #slide-tabs li:last-child a {
    border-radius:0 0 8px 0;
}
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* Colours
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 body {
    color:#F9F9F9;
    background-color:#06213F;
}
a {
    color:#55ABDA;
}
hr, .borderedbox {
    border-color:#D7D7D7;
}
label span {
    color:#FF0000;
    background-color:inherit;
}
.rounded {
    color:inherit;
    background-color:#F9F9F9;
}
/* Rows */
 .row0, .row0 a {
    color:#F9F9F9;
    background-color:#06213F;
}
.row1 {
    color:#979797;
    background-color:#06213F;
}
.row1 a {
    color:#F9F9F9;
    background-color:inherit;
}
.row2, .row2 a {
    color:#06213F;
    background-color:inherit;
}
.row3 {
    color:#979797;
    background-color:inherit;
}
.row4 {
    color:#979797;
    background-color:inherit;
}
.row5, .row5 a {
    color:#55ABDA;
    background-color:#06213F;
}
/* Top Bar */
 #topbar li {
    border-color:#FFFFFF;
}
/* Header */
 #header input {
    color:#979797;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
#header button {
    color:#F9F9F9;
    background-color:#55ABDA;
}
/* Homepage Slider */
 #slide-wrapper figure figcaption {
    color:#666666;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
#slide-wrapper figure figcaption:hover {
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#slider #slide-tabs li a {
    color:#666666;
    background-color:#DEDACB;
    border-color:#666666;
}
#slider #slide-tabs li a:hover, #slider #slide-tabs li.active a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#06213F;
}
/* Content Area */
 .container h1, .container h2, .container h3, .container h4, .container h5, .container h6, .container .heading {
    border-color:#D7D7D7;
}
#twitter {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#06213F;
}
#twitter div:first-child {
    border-color:#FFFFFF;
}
.listing li {
    border-color:#D7D7D7;
}
.quickinfo li a {
    color:#666666;
    background-color:#DEDACB;
}
.quickinfo li a:hover {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#06213F;
}
/* Footer */
 #footer .faico a {
    box-shadow:2px 2px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
#footer input {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#979797;
}
#footer button {
    color:#F9F9F9;
    background-color:#55ABDA;
}
/* Navigation */
 #mainav li a {
    color:inherit;
}
#mainav .active a, #mainav a:hover, #mainav li:hover > a {
    color:#55ABDA;
    background-color:inherit;
}
#mainav li li a, #mainav .active li a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
#mainav li li:hover > a, #mainav .active .active > a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#55ABDA;
}
#mainav form select {
    border-color:#D7D7D7;
}
#breadcrumb a {
    color:#888888;
    background-color:inherit;
}
#breadcrumb li:last-child a {
    color:#55ABDA;
}
.container .sidebar nav a {
    color:inherit;
    border-color:#D7D7D7;
}
.container .sidebar nav a:hover {
    color:#55ABDA;
}
.pagination a, .pagination strong {
    border-color:#D7D7D7;
}
.pagination .current strong {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#06213F;
}
/* Tables + Comments */
 table, th, td, #comments .avatar, #comments input, #comments textarea {
    border-color:#D7D7D7;
}
th {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#373737;
}
tr, #comments li, #comments input[type="submit"], #comments input[type="reset"] {
    color:inherit;
    background-color:#FBFBFB;
}
tr:nth-child(odd), #comments li:nth-child(odd) {
    color:inherit;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
table a, #comments a {
    background-color:inherit;
}
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* Media Queries
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 @-ms-viewport {
    width:device-width;
}
/* Smartphone + Tablet
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 @media screen and (min-width:180px) and (max-width:750px) {
    .imgl, .imgr {
        display:inline-block;
        float:none;
        margin:0 0 10px 0;
    }
    .fl_left, .fl_right {
        display:block;
        float:none;
    }
    .one_half, .one_third, .two_third, .one_quarter, .two_quarter, .three_quarter {
        display:block;
        float:none;
        width:auto;
        margin:0 0 30px 0;
        padding:0;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:180px) and (max-width:900px) {
    .wrapper {
        max-width:95%;
    }
    #topbar {
        text-align:center;
    }
    #header #logo {
        margin-bottom:15px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    #header #logo h1 {
        margin:0;
        line-height:1em;
    }
    #header form {
        max-width:250px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    #header input {
        min-width:0;
    }
    #mainav ul {
        display:none;
    }
    #mainav form {
        display:block;
    }
    #slide-wrapper figure figcaption {
        display:none;
    }
    #slider .view {
        display:block;
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    #slider .view:hover::before {
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        content:"";
        background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
        z-index:1;
    }
    #slider .view:hover::after {
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        width:36px;
        height:36px;
        margin:-18px 0 0 -18px;
        text-align:center;
        font-family:"FontAwesome";
        content:"\f05a";
        font-size:36px;
        line-height:36px;
        z-index:2;
    }
    #slider #slide-tabs li {
        display:block;
        float:none;
    }
    #slider #slide-tabs li a {
        width:100%;
        min-height:0;
        border-width:0 1px 1px 1px;
    }
    #slider #slide-tabs li:first-child a {
        border-radius:0;
    }
    #slider #slide-tabs li:last-child a {
        border-radius:0 0 8px 8px;
    }
    #twitter div {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    #twitter div:first-child {
        padding:15px 0;
        border-right:none;
    }
    .quickinfo li {
        max-width:250px;
    }
    #footer div:last-child {
        margin-bottom:0;
    }
    #footer figure.center {
        text-align:left;
    }
    #footer .faico li {
        margin:0 10px 10px 0;
    }
    #footer input {
        min-width:0;
    }
    #copyright {
        text-align:center;
    }
    #copyright p:first-of-type {
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
    #comments input[type="reset"] {
        margin-top:10px;
    }
    .pagination li {
        display:inline-block;
        margin:0 5px 5px 0;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:750px) and (max-width:900px) {
    .quickinfo {
        font-size:11px;
        line-height:1.2em;
    }
    .quickinfo li a {
        padding:20px 5px 0 85px;
    }
}
/* Max Wrapper Width
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 @media screen and (min-width:978px) {
    .wrapper {
        max-width:978px;
    }
}
/* Other
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 @media screen and (max-width:650px) {
    .scrollable {
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        margin:0 0 30px 0;
        padding:0 0 15px 0;
        overflow:auto;
        overflow-x:scroll;
    }
    .scrollable table {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
}
```